# Instantiating a Generic Interface

Tags: java, generics, anonymous-inner-class

I have an interface

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public void bar(String s, T t);
}
```

I want to write a method

```
public void baz() {
    String hi = "Hello";
    String bye = "Bye";
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo() {
        public void bar(String s, String t) {
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    };
    foo.bar(hi,bye);
}
```

i get an error

```
<anonymous Test$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method bar(String,Object) in Foo
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo() {
```

I'm fairly new to Java, I'm sure this is a simple mistake. how can I write this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using java 7, **Type inference** doesn't apply here. You have to provide the **Type parameter in the constructor invoking as well**.

```
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>() {
        public void bar(String s, String t) {
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    };
    foo.bar(hi,bye);
```

**EDIT:** just noticed that you have used `new Foo()` which is basically a raw type, you have to provide the generic type for your constructor invokation, `new Foo<String>()`

[**Related Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821586/why-cant-diamond-infer-types-on-anonymous-inner-classes)

Comment: Except the OP wasn't using the `<>` operator - he was using raw `Foo`.

Comment: Are you saying `new Foo` is the same as `new Foo<>` in Java 7? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: nopes, i never said that, they arent the same , `new Foo<>`(not for anonynymous class's though) would only work in java 7 due to introduction of type inference.

Comment: @PaulBellora sorry my explanation was vague, edited it now.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten one `<String>`

```
public void baz() {
    String hi = "Hello";
    String bye = "Bye";
    Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>() {
        public void bar(String s, String t) {
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    };
    foo.bar(hi,bye);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>() {
  @Override
  public void bar(String s, String t) {
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(s);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change with below code it compile and run perfectly.

```
        Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>() {
```